# How do we stop flickering on onmouseover and onmouseout

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

There are list of rows, When I hover on particular row this popup should be activated. How this can be done. Whenever I hover i get data popup works fine but it **flickers a lot** :(

This is my component.

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.SelectedWrapperItems}" var="vSWI" indexVar="index">
    <a href="{!'/one/one.app?#/sObject/' +vSWI.owOLI.OpportunityProductBundle__c + '/view'}"
       data-recId="{!vSWI.owOLI.OpportunityProductBundle__c}" data-index="{!index}"
       target="_blank" onmouseenter="{!c.handleMouseOver}" onmouseout="{!c.handleMouseOut}" 
       tabindex="-1">

        {!vSWI.owOLI.OpportunityProductBundle__r.Name}
        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.hoverRow==index}">
            <div style="padding-left: 2rem; padding-top: 5rem; position: relative;">
                <div class="slds-popover slds-popover_tooltip slds-nubbin_top-left slds-rise-from-ground" 
                    role="tooltip" id="help" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 15px;">
                    <div class="slds-popover__body"> 
                        Id: {!v.hoveropb.Id}
                        Name: {!v.hoveropb.Name}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>    
        </aura:if>      
    </a>
</aura:iteration >
```

This is my JS

```
handleMouseOver : function(component,event,helper){
    var id1=event.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-recId");
    var action=component.get("c.getopportunityBundleProducts");
    action.setParams({
        "bid":id1 
    });
    action.setCallback(this,function(re) { 
        var state=re.getState(); 
        if(state==='SUCCESS'){
            var items = component.find("hoveron");
            component.set("v.hoverRow", parseInt(event.target.dataset.index));
            component.set("v.hoveropb",re.getReturnValue());
        } 
    }); 
    $A.enqueueAction(action); 
},
handleMouseOut : function(component,event,helper){
    component.set("v.hoverRow",-1);
}
```

[My screencast](https://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cFhvDlbsLK)

Comment: Would it be possible to provide a short animation that visualizes the problem, or something we can copy-paste that exhibits the same behavior?

Comment: I have added the link  to my question sfdcfox.

Comment: It looks like there's something wrong with your styles. What's happening is that on mouseover, your row is growing in height, which triggers the mouseout, which shrinks the row, which triggers the mouseover... However, I'm not sure if the problem is here, or in the surrounding code.

Comment: Can you help me with any other working solutions. I am at stake, at  this moment. pretty high dependencies :(

Comment: Try using **onmouseleave** instead of **onmouseout** event. This might help, if yes, let me know, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use **onmouseleave** don't use **onmouseout**.